# Apache: Permission denied on 0777 directory

Tags: php, linux, apache, shell

I have shell script, that goes like:

```
#!/bin/bash
( cd /var/qwebirc; ls .git; )
```

And PHP file that executes the script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
exec("/var/qwebirc/pull.sh 2>&1", $arr);
```

Then when I call the shell script directly, I get the output I expect (ls of .git). When I call the PHP script from CLI, I get the very same output. But when the php script is called from browser, I get

> ls: cannot open directory .git: Permission denied

Okay, obviously permission problem of apache user. So I set 0777 to .git and all its files (for testing purposes). chown and chgrp to apache. Changed the script like:

```
( cd /var/qwebirc; pwd; whoami; ls -dl .git; ls .git; )
```

But the output in browser is still:

```
[0] => /var/qwebirc
[1] => apache
[2] => drwxrwxrwx. 8 apache apache 4096 Mar  1 03:59 .git
[3] => ls: cannot open directory .git: Permission denied
```

Which doesn't make much sense to me. Any idea what's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Your .git directory has permissions rwxrwsrwx and not rwxrwxrwx. The set group id on execute bit seems to be on. Reset it and retry.

Comment: Changed but still permission denied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is SELinux. Not exactly sure how its policies work (gotta look into that now), but after disabling SELinux, ls from apache started to work.